# how does iphone access sqlite database in my mac

Tags: ios, sqlite, database-connection

I am crating an app in Xcode which stores some user information in an SQLITE database called contacts.db in my mac in the documents folder and my simulator is able to pull it up. So everytime a new user sings up, it has to update this DB. 
If I publish this app and the app starts running in multiple iphones, will those iphones be able to access same database in my mac by default? 
If not how will you make iphones access this contacts.db running in my mac? How do I create that link?

Comment: Are you saying that when thousands of iPhone users around the world download your app from the App Store and start using the app, you want all of those copies of the app to access the database file on your home computer? Please say that this is *not* what you actually want.

Comment: rmaddy, thanks for the reply. could you please tell me what kind of database is normally used? I have used Xcode to program my app and SQLite as my DB for testing in the simulator. should I use a SQL server for storing the master data?

Comment: Your question is far too broad for a question here but if you need a central database that is accessed by all users of your app then you need a server to host your database and you need to provide an API that your app uses to access the database. Perhaps a solution with parse.com would meet your needs. Either way, you can't use a simple SQLite file on your home computer.

Answer (score 0):

There are different tools for that one of this is `iExplorer`. You can `Download` and `install` it on your mac and access you app data. :)